# On load of MapKit Map on iOS 12.0, all callouts are displayed instead of hidden

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, mapkit

**Context**

I have a Xamarin Forms app that uses native maps (Google Maps on Android, Apple Mapkit on iOS). After testing on a variety of Android and Apple phones and tablets, the map is displayed correctly except on an iPhone 6 running iOS 12.0.
<strike>This is weird especially since the map is working on iPhones older and newer than the iPhone 6.</strike> Actually, the issue seems to be with the latest version of iOS; updating the app to 12.0 causes the map to be displayed incorrectly. 
The map has a lot of annotations, and all annotations have a callout.

**Expected behavior:**

Map annotations are displayed once the map is opened. User should be able to tap on an annotation to open the associated callout, and when tapping on callout, they navigate to another page.

**Actual behavior:**

On <strike>an iPhone 6</strike> iOS 12.0, Map annotations are displayed but all callouts are also displayed, and the app hangs. When the user taps on the callout, the app crashes.

**Additional Information:**
We are using FreshMvvm as our Mvvm Framework.
We are using custom map renderers. The main structure of the map renderer goes like this:

```
public class IosDefaultMapRenderer : MapRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<View> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        var nativeMap = Control as MKMapView;
        if (e.OldElement != null && nativeMap != null)
        {
            nativeMap.RemoveAnnotations(nativeMap.Annotations);
            nativeMap.GetViewForAnnotation = null;
            nativeMap.CalloutAccessoryControlTapped -= OnCalloutAccessoryControlTapped;
            nativeMap.DidSelectAnnotationView -= OnDidSelectAnnotationView;
            nativeMap.DidDeselectAnnotationView -= OnDidDeselectAnnotationView;
            if (nativeMap.Overlays != null)
            {
                nativeMap.RemoveOverlays(nativeMap.Overlays);
            }
        }
        if (e.NewElement == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        _formsMap = (DefaultMap)e.NewElement; // Map from Xamarin Forms
        customPins = _formsMap.CustomPins;
        if (nativeMap == null) return;
        nativeMap.GetViewForAnnotation = GetViewForAnnotation;
        nativeMap.CalloutAccessoryControlTapped += OnCalloutAccessoryControlTapped;
        nativeMap.DidSelectAnnotationView += OnDidSelectAnnotationView;
        nativeMap.DidDeselectAnnotationView += OnDidDeselectAnnotationView;
        AddCustomPins(nativeMap);
    }

    protected void AddCustomPins (MKMapView nativeMap)
    {
        foreach (CustomPin customPin in customPins)
        {
            // Generate Annotation
            //

            // Add annotation
            nativeMap.AddAnnotation(annotation);
        }
    }

    protected void MapRendererOnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<View> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
    }

    public virtual MKAnnotationView GetViewForAnnotation(MKMapView mapView, IMKAnnotation annotation)
    {
        var description = new UILabel();
        var detailButton = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure);
        var annotationView = mapView.DequeueReusableAnnotation(AnnotationIdentifier);

        if (annotationView == null)
        {
            annotationView = new MKAnnotationView(annotation, AnnotationIdentifier);
        }
        else
        {
            annotationView.Annotation = annotation;
        }

        // Set annotationView and description properties from customPin data
        //

        return annotationView;
    }


    public void OnDidSelectAnnotationView(object sender, MKAnnotationViewEventArgs e)
    {
        // ...
    }

    protected virtual void OnCalloutAccessoryControlTapped(object sender, MKMapViewAccessoryTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        // navigate to another page
    }

    public void OnDidDeselectAnnotationView(object sender, MKAnnotationViewEventArgs e)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: iOS version for that iPhone 6?

Comment: iOS version for that iPhone 6 is 12.0. I've edited the post to include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved logic from `OnDidSelectAnnotationView` to `GetViewForAnnotation`.

This fixed the app crashing when a callout is tapped.

I also removed a line from which is setting the annotation to selected. `GetViewForAnnotation` seems to be called once for all annotations once the map is loaded, so all annotations are getting selected. It's weird since this wasn't happening in the previous version of iOS.

Comment: Did you able to find a solution for the callouts?

Comment: Yes @SalmanIqbal. There was a line where the annotation is getting opened/selected. Before iOS12, this was not called at the start. When you update to iOS 12, this was getting called when the map was loaded, leading to all callouts getting opened when the map is loaded. I had to remove this line.

Comment: I've used the customMKAnnotationView which inherits from MapKit.MKPinAnnotationView, in its constructor I've used this line **CanShowCallout = true;**
Earlier, I was using the **CanShowCallout** under this method **MKAnnotationView GetViewForAnnotation(MKMapView mapView, IMKAnnotation annotation)**
The map still shows the callout as open on first time loading of map.

Comment: I still have **CanShowCallout = true** under **GetViewForAnnotation**. I had to remove **annotationView.Selected = true;** to make my callouts not open when the map is first loaded.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple.
To hide callouts for iOS12, we just need to move map a little bit by changing region of the Map.

You may try this. Call below method from 'mapview didAdd views'

```
var isiOS12issueDone: Bool = false (Global variable)

func handleiOS12issue()
{
    if (isiOS12OrLater() && isiOS12issueDone == false)
    {
        var region = mvMapView!.region
        region.center.latitude += 0.000001
        mvMapView!.region = region

        isiOS12issueDone = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are really discouraged. To help future readers, please explain what you are doing too!